# What does this mysql error mean?

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, mysql, database

I'm on Xubuntu 13.10 64 bit. I know the password of my mysql database, but still can't login as root. I try to change the password

`sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

I get

```
[1] 8863
mypc ~: 140308 20:26:59 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
140308 20:26:59 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
140308 20:26:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

What does this error mean? Note I that changed the password but still can't login as root. So I'm curious about that particular error.

Note that I recently messed up `/var` permissions and fixed it according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431080/fixing-var-errors). Does that have anything to do with this issue?

Comment: Is this an error or a warning?

Comment: @arsaKasra I don't know but it seems like an error because after changing the password, I still can't access root, but honestly I don't know - something doesn't seem right about it, I want to know what's that